# How to configure MSAL to support AAD, Angular 7+, Azure Funcs

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I would like to understand how to configure MSAL and related artifacts to facilitate the following configuration.

- Frontend Angular 7+ website/app published to Azure Storage account and served as a static website.
- Backend Azure Functions API project for performing CRUD operations on a Cosmos-DB database
- Both the Angular website frontend and the Azure Functions API backend should be restricted to individuals within our Azure Active Directory.

I attempted to learn how to configure MSAL for my intended use-case by studying this demonstration project: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md. Unfortunately, that project refers to an API backend site that is no longer operational. And the backend bits are not included in the repository.

The demonstration project `msal-microsoft-authentication-library-for-js\lib\msal-angular\samples\MSALAngularDemoApp` doesn't work as published. Log-in attempts fail. Once encounters `Uncaught (in promise): AADSTS650052: The app needs access to a service (\"api://a88bb933-319c-41b5-9f04-eff36d985612\") that your organization \"<MY-ORG>\" has not subscribed to or enabled.`

With my current configuration, in the browser I'm encountering request cancellation when MSAL attempts to make a requests of the following form:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/67ba7efb-e8.....52-1f993843c3a0/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fte.....nfuncs.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=61601ca6-104.....524550f6ec&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=62877cb9e.....245f7f613_2019.....72304&state=redir%3D%252Fapi%252Fpeople%253Fcode%253DqJH4Bs%252F.....ameK%252FPh5S5Th%252FXttS.....D%253D%2526name-starts-with%253Dji

So I'm clearly doing at least one thing wrong. Following is a summary of my configuration. However, rather than attempting to debug my configuration, it might prove easier (more efficient) to describe all steps required to establish a working configuration.

```
Azure Function App
Platform features
    Authentication / Authorization
        App Service Authentication: On
        Action to take when request is not authenticated
            Log in with Azure Active Directory
        Authentication Providers
            Azure Active Directory Configured (Express: Existing App)
            Advanced Settings Token Store
            ALLOWED EXTERNAL REDIRECT URLS
                Link to static website of storage container where Angular site is deployed
                E.g., https://<storagecontainer>.z5.web.core.windows.net/
    CORS
    ALLOWED ORIGINS
        https://<storagecontainer>.z5.web.core.windows.net/
        http://localhost:4200
Function Signatures
    `public static async Task<IActionResult> Function1([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", "options", Route = null)] HttpRequest httpRequest, ILogger log) {`
```

Comment: I was able to get AAD-authentication working with _Angular + AZ Storage Static Website + AZ Funcs backend_ using `adal-angular` rather than `msal-angular` _(MSAL.js)_. I adapted [Pete Skelly's example](https://peteskelly.com/secure-functions-aad-3/) for Angular 7.2. I used `@auth0/angular-jwt` instead of `angular2-jwt` for compatibility with RxJs 6.3.

Comment: Sounds like a good answer to me @CalvinDale